# No bold on the newtheorem in the latest ACM latex template

Tags: formatting, templates, acm

Recently I applied latest ACM proceeding template (available in [ACM ACM SIG Proceedings Templates](http://www.acm.org/publications/article-templates/proceedings-template.html/) link "ACM LaTeX2e Style File VERSION 2.8 (May 2015 CLS)") with my papers. The generated pdf is OK but some minor changes seems strange.

One change is `\newtheorem`. My previous code:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}



\newtheorem{myDefine}{Definition}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Rule}
\newtheorem{myFind}{Finding}
\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,breaklines=false}

\begin{document}

\begin{myDefine}
The given two method handle graphs $G_{mh}$ = ($V$, $E$) and $G_{mh'}$ = ($V'$, $E'$) are equivalent if there exists two mapping functions, i.e., $f: V \to V'$ and $g: E \to E'$, so that the conditions $f(u) \in V', f(v) \in V'$, and $g(\{f(u),f(v)\}) \in E'$ are also true for any $u \in V, v \in V$, and \{$u,v$\} $\in E$. $G_{mh}$ represents the MHG that starts from the method handle $mh$.
\label{define1}
\end{myDefine} 

\end{document}
```

[[image: Original]]
[[image: With latest template]]

As you can see, with latest template, the "Definition" and "Rule" in the original template are bold but not in the latest template.

How can I change the template so that it can be consistent with original ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to redefine some internal commands (`\@begintheorem` and `\@opargbegintheorem`):

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}

\makeatletter
\def\@begintheorem#1#2{%
    \parskip 0pt % GM July 2000 (for tighter spacing)
    \trivlist
    \item[%
        \hskip 10\p@
        \hskip \labelsep
        {{\bfseries #1\hskip 5\p@\relax#2.}}%
    ]
    \it
}
\def\@opargbegintheorem#1#2#3{%
    \parskip 0pt % GM July 2000 (for tighter spacing)
    \trivlist
    \item[%
        \hskip 10\p@
        \hskip \labelsep
        {\bfseries #1\ #2\       % This mod by Gerry to enumerate corollaries
   \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{(#3)}  % and bracket the 'corollary title'
        \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa>\z@ % and retain the correct numbering of e.g. theorems
            \hskip 5\p@\relax    % if they occur 'around' said corollaries.
            \box\@tempboxa       % Gerry - Nov. 1999.
        \fi.}%
    ]
    \it
}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{myDefine}{Definition}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Rule}
\newtheorem{myFind}{Finding}

\begin{document}

\begin{myDefine}
\label{define}
A test definition
\end{myDefine} 

\begin{mydef}
\label{rule}
A test rule
\end{mydef} 

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

The original definitions have `\sc` (old command!) instead of the `\bfseries` in two places in my example code.

Take into account that the change was made in Spring 2013 according to the new specifications for ACM conferences and journals, so for new conferences and journals most probably they will undo your modification.

Comment: W.R.T. the  `\\\` bug, this seems fine